# SwiftHttp + JSONDecoder

Tags: json, swift

I'm try to parse a json response from a server like this

```
HTTP.GET(ServerPatientApi.SPLASH, parameters: nil) { response in
            if let error = response.error {
                listener.onException(error)
                return;
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
                let res = try decoder.decode(PatientSplashModel.self, from: response.data)
                listener.onSplashLoaded()
            })
        }
```

But I'm receiving the error below:

> > Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@convention(block)

at the block:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
                let res = try decoder.decode(PatientSplashModel.self, from: response.data)
                listener.onSplashLoaded()
            })
```

I think the error caused by:

> > PatientSplashModel.self

how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: show you json response and `PatientSplashModel` model

Comment: please add JSON example and model info.

Comment: json is ok. because i'm using the same API for Android. The error happend BEFORE json - on compilation state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, you have to wrap the `try` statement in a `do catch` block

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    do {
        let res = try decoder.decode(PatientSplashModel.self, from: response.data)
        listener.onSplashLoaded()
    } catch { print(error) }
 }
```

Comment: Now I'm receiving the follogin error: Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicitThe error was fixed by adding changing decoder to self.decoder